# When using SQLCMD on windows is there any way to use DSNs?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sqlcmd, dsn

Rather than configuring connection information directly through each and every sqlcmd command, looking to use DSNs to have that information stored in a centralized location.

However when referring to the [documentation given](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver17) on sqlcmd:

> **-D**
> Interprets the server name provided to -S as a DSN instead of a hostname. For more information, see *DSN Support in sqlcmd and bcp* in [Connecting with sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-sqlcmd?view=sql-server-ver16).
>
> > **Note**
> > The -D option is only available on Linux and MacOS clients. On Windows clients, it previously referred to a now-obsolete option which has been removed and is ignored.

Is there anyway on windows to utilize DSNs when using SQLCMD? Seems strange that this functionality would be removed and limited to only MacOS and Linux.

Comment: This isn't related to the SQL _language_, so I removed that tag. Perhaps you should add <sql-server> instead.

Comment: But dsn never stores passwords on windows, do you want your commands to bring up the dreaded dialog?

Comment: I think that's true for the system DNS but there's a section for file DSN within the ODBC administrator as well. Unless I'm mistaken the password could be stored there